# Node.js module.js:472 throw err;

Tags: node.js

I just started with Nodejs and right at the beginning I have a problem when I try to run some basic code in terminal. I installed Nodejs and npm using homebrew and when I try to run

```
node filename.js
```

I get this error:

```
`module.js:472
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/TanjaIvan/global.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:542:3`
```

I already tried uninstalling Nodejs and reinstalling it but no help. Current version of Nodejs is v7.10.0 and npm is 4.2.0.
Can someone help me with this error so I can continue with my tutorial?
Thank you

Comment: the file name is global.js and the content of it is cosole.log("Hello World");

Comment: I am sorry for this question the problem is that I saved the file in a different location. Stupid misstake. You can close this :)

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help section. A good post will get informative answers